# Flutter excessive rates

Tags: flutter

I have a question about the flutter technology.

I have a mobile application online for a few months and I want to make changes to the design, my developers count me 4 days of work to migrate flutter to its new version.

Also, they ask me :

3 days of work to add the connection with Facebook / Google / Apple

4 working days to integrate the payment with Apple Pay.

Don't these rates seem excessive?

Thank you for your time and reading.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Migrating flutter to the new version is, if they look to migrate to Flutter 2.0, not a lot of time. This of course depends on the size of the codebase, but Flutter 2.0 broke **a lot** of shit.

3 days for an OAUTH2 connection with Facebook/Google/Apple seems fair. It takes quite a bit of boilerplate and it's difficult to set up at first.

Apple pay I wouldn't know, but I can imagine 4 days is fair, especially if it's the first time you're working with it.